# Encapsulating data definitions in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, syntax

I am trying to define a data type using other data types like this:

```
data A = Something String | SomethingElse Int

data B = Another B | YetAnother A

data C = A | B

x :: [ C ]
x = [ YetAnother (SomethingElse 0), Something "Hello World" ]
```

But this is giving me an error saying that I cannot have a type A when expecting a type B. Why is this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing the data constructors for `C`.

```
data A = Something String
       | SomethingElse Int

data B = Another    B
       | YetAnother A

data C = C0 A
       | C1 B

x :: [ C ]
x = [ C1 (YetAnother (SomethingElse 0))
    , C0 (Something "Hello World")
     ]
```

Answer (score 4):

The `A` and `B` in `data C = A | B` are declarations of new data constructors, not references to your existing types `A` and `B`.  (Constructors are not optional in `data` declarations.)

Answer (score 0):

Haskell does not have true "union" types, unions in Haskell must be tagged with constructors. (see [Wikipedia > Tagged union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union)).

[Either](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#t%3aEither) is the general-purpose tagged union type in Haskell, where data is tagged as `Left` or `Right`.

```
data Either a b = Left a | Right b
```