# Why does Haskell hide functions with the same name but different type signatures?

Tags: haskell, types, language-design

Suppose I was to define `(+)` on Strings but not by giving an instance of `Num String`.

Why does Haskell now hide `Num`s `(+)` function? After all, the function I have provided:

```
(+) :: String -> String -> String
```

can be distinguished by the compiler from Prelude's `(+)`. Why can't both functions exist in the same namespace, but with different, non-overlapping type signatures?

As long as there is no call to the function in the code, Haskell to care that there's an ambiguitiy. Placing a call to the function with arguments will then determine the types, such that appropriate implementation can be chosen.

Of course, once there is an instance `Num String`, there would actually be a conflict, because at that point Haskell couldn't decide based upon the parameter type which implementation to choose, if the function were actually called.
In that case, an error should be raised.

Wouldn't this allow function overloading without pitfalls/ambiguities?

Note: I am *not* talking about dynamic binding.

Comment: As others have said, Haskell only provides overloading via type classes.  This isn't the only way to design a language, but it has the nice property that you can actually give types to program fragments, e.g., `(+)` has type `(Num a) => a -> a -> a`.  With your suggestion there would be no type that could be given to `(+)`.

Comment: this would not be a Hindley-Milner type system then. Type inference would be more complicated. The type of `(+)` would have to be a true union, and ["''true union'' types are not present in Haskell"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13238975). If it were allowed, some typos would get accepted as well-typed programs. There's no ambiguity with the [tagged union types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) (i.e. when we are [forced to use type constructors](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10610339) explicitly).

Comment: @WillNess Is there a good reason why a "Hindley-Milner type system" should be better than what he proposed? What are the advantages of it? And what are the downsides of the proposal?

Comment: @Odin perhaps its type inference algorithm is simpler.

Answer (score 20):

Haskell simply does not support function overloading (except via typeclasses). One reason for that is that function overloading doesn't work well with type inference. If you had code like `f x y = x + y`, how would Haskell know whether `x` and `y` are Nums or Strings, i.e. whether the type of `f` should be `f :: Num a => a -> a -> a` or `f :: String -> String -> String`?

PS: This isn't really relevant to your question, but the types aren't strictly non-overlapping if you assume an open world, i.e. in some module somewhere there might be an instance for `Num String`, which, when imported, would break your code. So Haskell never makes any decisions based on the fact that a given type does not have an instance for a given typeclass. Of course, function definitions hide other function definitions with the same name even if there are no typeclasses involved, so as I said: not really relevant to your question.

---

Regarding why it's necessary for a function's type to be known at the definition site as opposed to being inferred at the call-site: First of all the call-site of a function may be in a different module than the function definition (or in multiple different modules), so if we had to look at the call site to infer a function's type, we'd have to perform type checking across module boundaries. That is when type checking a module, we'd also have to go all through the modules that import this module, so in the worst case we have to recompile all modules every time we change a single module. This would greatly complicate and slow down the compilation process. More importantly it would make it impossible to compile libraries because it's the nature of libraries that their functions will be used by other code bases that the compiler does not have access to when compiling the library.

Comment: Hmm, but the minute you introduce an instance for `Num String`, they *do* overlap, *before* they don't. Why couldn't Haskell complain when there actually is a problem, instead of being "overly pessimistic"? As for your first question: Why does Haskell *have* to care? Before you call the function, at which time you know the type of the argument, it doesn't need to know. When you do call it, the type will be determined.

Comment: @phant0m What you think of is kind of dynamic dispatch at runtime. But type checking (likel told you) happens at compile time.

Comment: @Ingo I'm fully aware of that. How does my post/comment imply dynamic dispatch?

Comment: @phant0m It does imply it implicitly, at least. You say *when the function is called*, and I see this could be a sloppy way to say: *when the compiler sees a function application*. If it is this what you mean, then please give the type of `f x y = x + x + y + y`

Comment: @Ingo Yes, that's exactly what I mean. But you haven't placed a call to `f` in your source, have you? Which is why I woulnd't yet fully determine the function's type.

Comment: @phant0m Hence, you admit you couldn't type a module that has just this definition (and the definition of the overloaded (+), of course), and nothing else? So this is why Haskell does *not* do it this way.

Comment: @phant0m What you're proposing would require type checking to occur across module boundaries and would make it impossible to type check libraries (because in your proposal type checking can't happen until the call site is visited and when writing a library there is no call site).

Comment: I should have to use `f`, what if I just define it and export it?

Comment: @Ingo Agreed, but it means it may just not be practical, not impossible, right?

Comment: @sepp2k Thanks, that makes sense. Can you integrate this into your answer? From what I understood until now, that seems to be the gist of it.

Answer (score 7):

> As long as the function isn't called
>
> At some point, **when** using the function

no no no. In Haskell you don't think of "before" or "the minute you do...", but define stuff once and for all time. That's most apparent in the runtime behaviour of variables, but also translates to function signatures and class instances. This way, you don't have to do all the tedious thinking about compilation order and are safe from the many ways e.g. C++ templates/overloads often break horribly because of one tiny change in the program.

Also, I don't think you quite understand how Hindley-Milner works.

> Before you call the function, at which time you know the type of the argument, it doesn't need to know.

Well, you normally *don't* know the type of the argument! It may sometimes be explicitly given, but usually it's deduced from the other argument or the return type. For instance, in

```
map (+3) [5,6,7]
```

the compiler doesn't know what types the numeric literals have, it only knows that they are numbers. This way, you can evaluate the result as whatever you like, and that allows for things you could only dream of in other languages, for instance a symbolic type where

```
> map (+3) [5,6,7] :: SymbolicNum
[SymbolicPlus 5 3, SymbolicPlus 6 3, SymbolicPlus 7 3]
```

Comment: "no no no", I know Haskell doesn't do that. The question is about *why*.

Comment: @phant0m Because compile-time type checking avoids loads of irritating and hard-to-debug runtime errors, and allows optimisation by specialisation, for example. Late binding is not the performance&correctness-neutral panacea you seem to think it is.

Comment: @AndrewC I'm not talking about late binding.

Comment: Sorry - I misinterpreted your phrase "At some point, when using the function, the type of the argument will be determined,". I realise from your response you meant "At some point in the code, where the function is used, the type of the argument will be determined,". It does sound a bit like you want duck typing or at least to abolish classes altogether. Why does your function need to be called (+) anyway? Surely it'd be deeply confusing for anyone reading your code. I think VBA does this, and I think it's ugly.

Comment: @AndrewC: actually, many languages allow concatenating strings with `+` (right away I can think of Javascript, C++, Python, even Java) so many programmers might actually not be too confused; but I also don't like this. After all, you'd expect addition to be a group operation / to have at least a partial inverse, wouldn't you? String concatenation is merely a monoid operation, so Haskell's `<>` (or simply `++`!) is much more natural for this.

Comment: @AndrewC Sorry, I realized this is confusing after having to explain it quite a few times in comments here, but I didn't know any better way to word. I'll steal that from you :)

Comment: @leftaroundabout <shudder/> Yes. They make a special magic case for (+). I meant it could be deeply confusing in general. Does the use of `fmap` mean there's a Functor, or just that you happened to use the name `fmap` without making a Functor instance? Does the use of `>>` mean I'm in a monad, or just that I liked the shape and fancied using it for `flip (.)`? Nnnnnng! !?*!

Comment: @AndrewC As for why the function needs to be called `(+)`: It's not about plus. I'm just trying to understand the decisions that have been made while designing Haskell.

Comment: @phant0m I was trying to say that I think it would be even worse for functions other than (+) (which has a history elsewhere of being non-structuredly overloaded). At the moment the type of the function is deducible directly from the name, and any parametric or class-overloading can be resolved at the call site. Your proposal would break that and make a many-many relationship from names to types. Type/constructor classes are a powerful way to overload functions, and I think it's better to choose a different name for a function that has a completely different meaning; strings aren't numbers.